# MVC and EF 5 Seed method does not populate the database tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am working on the Contoso University Application for MVC 4 and EF 5 from here https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I have followed the tutorial as is but, the database tables are not generated. Not sure about the issue. It looks like the database is connected well but the tables folder is empty.

How should I troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I think it is just the versioning issue with MVC 4. Try a different version.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following into the `<entityFramework></entityFramework>` section in the `web.config` file as following:

```
<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
        <context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
            <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
        </context>
    < /contexts>    
    <!-- ... -->
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: The code section was automatically deleted! It should be the following:  < entityFramework >
     < contexts >
   < context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
    < databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
   < /context>
  < /contexts>    
     ........
 < /entityFramework>
(Remove the spaces)

Comment: This should be added inside the < entityFramework>< /entityFramework> section in the Web.config file

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the connection string used in the tutorial. Let entity framework use the default connection.